# Blurred text with Freetype and OpenGL

Tags: c++, c, opengl, freetype

I'm trying to render text from Freetype using OpenGL with a fixed size on the screen (zoom independent).
For now I able to achieve the last point, but, the text is not equivalent to another program on the same OS and the same font with the same size.

[image]

On the left it's my program, on the right it's gedit. As you can see, my text looks a bit cropped and blurred on the y axis.
I can't figure out the problem

This is how I compute my vertex:

```
vec2 v = visibility * ((camera * vec3(char_position.xy, 1)).xy + vertex.xy / viewport * 2.);
```

And here what I do in my fragment shader

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(colorFrag.xyz, texture2D(tex, textureCoordFrag).a);
```

Comment: What is the texture size and the size on the screen - are they the same?

Comment: Yes, I counted the pixels, the size seems to be correct. To check it I used FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes and printed a '|'

Comment: assuming the texcoords are right, it looks like the vertex coords arent. maybe the are p[laced in the pixel centers instead of  the pixel corners.

Comment: You suppose that they are not aligned ? Could it come from the 'vertex.xy / viewport * 2.' ? I still don't understand why I do * 2, if I don't the text is two time smaller than in gedit

Answer (score 0):

So, as derhass mentionned in his commentary, my problem is that my pixels are not aligned and cause this blur.
I didn't find how to fix it well, but as quick fix I add half pixel size to the final coordinate

```
v.y += 1. / viewport.y;
```